# Unit Test multi target frameworks: Test all frameworks

Tags: .net, mstest

I create a MS Test Unit test project with these targets

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.2;net472</TargetFrameworks>
```

If I use this code in one my tests:

```cs
#if NET472
            Assert.Fail();
#endif
```

and then run the test, it will be successful. It means the tests are executed with `netcoreapp` target framework.

I want to do tests in both frameworks. How can I do that with a SINGLE test project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if using command line `dotnet test` it will run tests for each framework separately.